# How can I get Data obj from AES.GCM.Nonce - swift

Tags: swift, encryption, aes, apple-cryptokit

I am using `AES.GCM.seal(textData, using: retrievedKey)`, to encrypt some information.  I need access to `encrypted.nonce` as a Data.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The `Data` type has an initializer that accepts any type that conforms to the `Sequence` protocol. You can use it to initialize a `Data` from `AES.GCM.Nonce` because the definition of `AES.GCM.Nonce` shows that it conforms to the `Sequence` protocol:

```swift
public struct Nonce : ContiguousBytes, Sequence
```

So you can easily do this:

```swift
let nonceData = Data(encrypted.nonce)
```

and you will get a `Data` from your `AES.GCM.Nonce`.